# Optional Exception handling

Tags: java, exception

I'm creating a wrapper for a very basic AI API. When something goes wrong in this API it does not throw any exception or elsehow reports a problem.

It is possible to recognise an error before an API call is called (ex. wrong argument).

In the wrapper I want to implement an error indication by throwing runtime exception. For now the client can decide whether he wants to handle them or not. In exceptional cases I throw a checked exception but there is a very good reason for it.

The problem is that when any exception is thrown the program stops and it needs to continue regardless. I was thinking stop throwing exceptions and just report the problem as warning in the logger but then client does not know that an error occurred.

The AI calls a method for update every second say.

Handling checked exceptions is nasty and code gets very ugly for even calling a very simple call.

Comment: This sounds like what IllegalArgumentException was born for.  Just have the client that calls this class catch the exception and handle it appropriately.  It need not be nasty or ugly, even for complex calls.

Comment: If you don't want to define checked Exceptions, you can still catch unchecked Excpetions, and make sure you have a code block that catchs them.

Comment: +1 for `IllegalArgumentException`. Also remember `IllegalStateException` for when "argument" just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IllegalArgumentException or create your custom Exceptions based on your needs, just by extending Exception class or implementing Throwable. Then you can manage the behaviour of your application. But you need to ensure that the blocks are surrounded by try-catch so then you can manage them, the API shoudl throw exception, you need to catch it in the try-catch-block. For instance:

```
try {
 String var = IamUsingThisAPI.methodOfTheAPI();
} catch (Exception e) { // You can create your custom Exception
 //maybe print stack trace but handle as you want
 System.out.println("Handling the exception");
 // Do something
 // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can provide methods like:

```
public void doSomethingQuiet(...) {
    try {
        doSomething(...);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.warn(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public void doSomething(...) throws Exception {
    if (incorrectArgs) {
        throw new Exception("Incorrect arguments!");
    }
    // process
}
```

You can also change method names to more 'natural': doSomethingQuiet -> doSomething and doSomething -> doSomethingThrowEx